# PHP HTTP post - 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, http, post, http-status-code-400

I'm not a PHP programmer by trade, but am in a bind having to code a PHP script that will send an HTTP POST request to an API.  This post also includes some JSON content (which I've verified is correctly formatted using jsonlint.com).  I'm continually getting "400 Bad Request" so I'm assuming I have something formatted incorrectly.

```
$json = "<JSON markup goes here>";

$options = array(
    'http' => array
    (
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $json,
        'header'  =>    "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                "Accept: application/json\r\n" .
                "Api-User: <API USER GOES HERE>\r\n" .
                "Api-Key: <API KEY GOES HERE>\r\n"
    )
);

$url = "https://url/paths";

$context  = stream_context_create( $options );
$result   = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );
$response = json_decode( $result );
```

I've searched this site and most of the examples seem to match up with what I'm doing...so I'm at a loss as to what the problem is.  The one difference I noticed (vs. the examples) is that mine is posting to an HTTPS url...but from what I've read, that doesn't really make much of a difference.  Any help you guys can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the api your connecting to? Often they provide documentation regarding why status codes are returned.

Comment: I don't see any "host" header.

Comment: Unfortunately, the API documentation only says "The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax." for their 400 Bad Request.  :-/  That's what made me think it was something I was doing wrong in the building of the request.

Comment: Error 400 may be just a normal response from the API. For example Mailchimp API gives this, when one tries to add already existing user to a mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this -- instead of putting json as a string, use PHP:

```
$json = array("keys" => "values"); // You get the idea, right?  

$options = array(
    'http' => array
    (
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => json_encode($json),
        'header'  =>    "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                "Accept: application/json\r\n" .
                "Api-User: <API USER GOES HERE>\r\n" .
                "Api-Key: <API KEY GOES HERE>\r\n"
    )
);
```

Comment: The JSON is pretty complex, which is why I wasn't using PHP to build it.  Here's a sample:

{"content": {"templateId": "123456"},"updateProfile": true,"recipients": [{"email": "jerry.garcia@gmail.com","id": "jerry.garcia@gmail.com","profile": {"userAttrs": [{"lastName": "Garcia"},{"firstName": "Jerry"},{"Birth Date": "1942-08-01"}]},"subscriptions": {"add": ["Banjo Lovers","9 finger club"]}}]}

If you can help me format that JSON using your method, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any "host" header.  Not including the "host" could result in a Bad Request.

For instance:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/myService HTTP/1.1
Host: http://localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "id" : "value"
}
```

Also, all of the examples in the doc use `fopen` instead of `file_get_contents`.  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php

**Edit:** Here's an example...

```
$options = array(
    'http' => array
    (
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $json,
        'header'  => "Host: http://localhost:8080\r\n" .
                "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                "Accept: application/json\r\n" .
                "Api-User: <API USER GOES HERE>\r\n" .
                "Api-Key: <API KEY GOES HERE>\r\n"
    )
);

$url = "http://localhost:8080/api/myService";
```

Comment: How would I define that in the $options array?  I'm assuming it would just be "Host: https://url/path"?  Is the Host my server or their server (where the API resides)?

Answer (score -1):

You may need to use curl:

```
<?php

function getCurl($url, $post) {

    $appName = 'My Application';
    $apiUser = [Username Goes Here];
    $apiKey = [API Key Goes Here];

    $baseUrl = "https://url/";
    $credentials = $apiUser:$apiKey;
    $typeHeader = "Content-Type: application/json";
    $helloHeader = "User-Agent: $appName ($appContact)";

    $url = $baseUrl.$url;

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $credentials);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($typeHeader, $helloHeader));
    return $ch;
}

$options = array(
    'http' => array
    (
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $json,
        'header'  =>    "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                "Accept: application/json\r\n" .
                "Api-User: <API USER GOES HERE>\r\n" .
                "Api-Key: <API KEY GOES HERE>\r\n"
    )
);

$curl = getCurl("paths", $options);
echo curl_exec($curl).'</br>';
echo curl_errno($curl).'</br>';
echo curl_error($curl).'</br>';

?>
```

Comment: I tried this method and it doesn't seem to recognize the API username and key when the information is sent.  Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure - maybe try removing some of the curl_setopt, such as CURLOPT_USERPWD especially since you're supplying that info in the $options array

Comment: Downvoted, as using CURL doesn't change the error and is more complex than using pure PHP.